# @RequestMapping annotation returning wrong URL

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

When I run TomCat it looks like the mapping is done correctly.

Console information:

INFORMATIONS: Mapped "{[/cervejas/novo]}" onto public java.lang.String com.algaworks.brewer.controller.CervejasController.novo()

However, when I try do call the following URL: localhost:8080/brewer/cervejas/novo an error HTTP Status 404 is returned.

I'm getting the following Tomcat warning on the console when I try to access the mapped URL on browser:

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/brewer/cervejas/cerveja/ CadastroCerveja] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

There is one more "directory" (cervejas) in URI.

WebConfig.java file:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.config;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

import com.algaworks.brewer.controller.CervejasController;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { CervejasController.class } )
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

CervejasController.java file:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CervejasController {

    @RequestMapping("/cervejas/novo")
    public String novo() {
        return "cerveja/CadastroCerveja";
    }

}
```

CadastroCerveja.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
    <h1>Olá ! Thymeleaf configurado.</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

WebConfig.java file:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.config;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

import com.algaworks.brewer.controller.CervejasController;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { CervejasController.class } )
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Package Explorer:

[image]

I could not locate the error. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access URL which is not defined in your controller: ***/brewer/cervejas/novo***

If you are not configured a ***ContextPath*** for your application somewhere either in `application.properties` or some `Configuration Class` than you should make it work by choosing one of the options below:

- Define context-path in `application.properties` file by putting `server.servlet.context-path=/brewer` property
- Make your Controller base mapping point to `/brewer` as follows:

  ```
  package com.algaworks.brewer.controller;

  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/brewer")
  public class CervejasController {

      @RequestMapping("/cervejas/novo")
      public String novo() {
          return "cerveja/CadastroCerveja";
      }
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I include the second option and the mapping appears correct: INFORMATIONS: Mapped "{[/brewer/cervejas/novo]}" onto public java.lang.String com.algaworks.brewer.controller.CervejasController.novo()
fev 02, 2019 2:31:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache.
But still returning the same error: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/brewer/cervejas/novo] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
fev 02, 2019 2:32:07 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

Comment: I include the WebConfig.java file in problem description.

Comment: Sorry. I found the error. I forgot to put the Bean annotation in WebConfig.java file (public ViewResolver viewResolver method). Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add your request type (GET, POST, etc.) to your controller method as follows:

Note: I dont know which request method you are trying to access the URI but i am assuming it is a GET request. You should change the request type according to your needs.

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/brewer")
public class CervejasController {

    @RequestMapping("/cervejas/novo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String novo() {
        return "cerveja/CadastroCerveja";
    }
}
```